# SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. Only on linux, it works on windows

Tags: linux, c++11, segmentation-fault, enet

I have been stuck on this for hours, for some reason I am getting a Segmentation fault error only on Linux. It only happens with packets of length 17 or more characters. I am using **[Enet](http://enet.bespin.org/)** library to send the packets. Anyone can help me out, I don't know what I am missing here ...

Here is a screenshot of gdb output
[image: Here is a screenshot of gdb output]
Here is the server side sample:

```
void GameServer::start()
{
if (!m_isRunning)
    m_isRunning = true;

ENetEvent  event;
//ENetPacket *packet;

while (m_isRunning)
{
    while (enet_host_service(server, &event, 1000) > 0)
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_CONNECT:
            std::cout << "A new client connected from ";
            std::cout << event.peer->address.host << " ";
            std::cout << event.peer->address.port << std::endl;

            break;
        case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_DISCONNECT:
            printf("%s disconnected.\n", event.peer->data);
            delete (char*)event.peer->data;
            break;
        case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_RECEIVE:
        {
            std::cout << "A packet of length ";
            std::cout << event.packet->dataLength;
            std::cout << " containing ";
            std::cout << event.packet->data;
            std::cout << " was received from ";
            printf("%s", event.peer->data);
            std::cout << " on channel ";
            std::cout << event.channelID << std::endl;

            // Split the packet data, ex:   packettype:data:data
            std::vector<std::string> tokens;
            std::string data;
            std::istringstream split((const char *)event.packet->data);

            // Process the packet data
            while (std::getline(split, data, ':')) Line 89: Crash here
                tokens.push_back(data);

            if (tokens.size() > 1)
            {

                //pc = player connected so we will broadcast the name to all peers
                if (tokens[0] == "pc")
                {
                    if (tokens.size() == 2)
                    {
                        char* data = new char[tokens[1].length() + 1];
                        strcpy(data, tokens[1].c_str());
                        event.peer->data = (void*)data;
                        for (size_t i = 0; i < server->connectedPeers; i++)
                        {
                            enet_host_broadcast(server, 0, event.packet);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //ma = message all so we are going to broadcast the message to all peers
                else if (tokens[0] == "ma") 
                {
                    if (tokens.size() == 2)
                    {
                        enet_host_broadcast(server, 0, event.packet);
                    }
                }


                /* One could just use enet_host_service() instead. */
                enet_host_flush(server);
            }
            /* Clean up the packet now that we're done using it. */
            enet_packet_destroy(event.packet);
            break;
        }
        case ENET_EVENT_TYPE_NONE:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}

}
```

Here is how the packet is created by the client and then sent to the server.

```
if (connected) {
        std::cout << "Input: ";
        std::string str = "";
        std::getline(std::cin, str);

        if (str.length() == 0) { continue; }

        packet = enet_packet_create(str.c_str(), str.length() + 1, ENET_PACKET_FLAG_RELIABLE);
        enet_peer_send(peer, 0, packet);

    }
```

If code sample if not enough I can provide more.

Comment: What is `GameServer::start` in `gameserver.cpp` around line 89?

Comment: I have updated the code sample to add the full start method.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but `event.peer->data = (void*)data;` seems suspicious since `data` (rvalue) resides on the stack for only that small block.  How long does it need to do anything with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crash in `malloc()` usually means that someone wrote over the end of an allocated buffer some time *earlier*.  That buffer overrun corrupted the pointers that get stored in free memory to link free blocks together.  It didn't cause a problem until `malloc()` tried to use those pointers.  Then BOOM!

Post the declaration of the event.packet type.  Are you sure data[] is big enough for the data you put in it?

Comment: I have edited question and added the requested code sample for the creation of the packet.

Comment: You could be overrunning a buffer anywhere.  It might seem to work on Windows just because you got lucky with placement of some allocations.

Comment: enet_host_broadcast will cause the packet to be destroyed.  You should not also call enet_packet_destroy on the packet when you do this.  It can cause problems like this

Comment: Also, you probably can't use the same packet in multiple calls to enet_host_broadcast

Comment: @MattTimmermans thank you very much! Removing the call to enet_packet_destroy worked. I got confused reading the documentation as it does not explicitly say to not call the destroy function. It instead says  "as with enet_peer_send()" -__-. Again, thank you for your time. The Lesson of the day read twice, code once!